# How to colorize a word with curses while typing?

Tags: python, curses

i'm new to curses library, and i am trying to colorize the stdin but haven't done yet. I wrote the following codes but they didn't work as i wish, can anyone help me to show how to colorize the stdin?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import curses

stdscr = curses.initscr()
curses.start_color()
curses.init_pair(1, curses.COLOR_RED, curses.COLOR_BLACK)
stdscr.nodelay(1)

q = 1
x = set()

while q != ord("q"):
    if len(x) == 3:
        stdscr.addstr(0,0, "def", curses.color_pair(1))
    if q == ord("d"):
        x.add("d")
    elif q == ord("e"):
        x.add("e")
    elif q == ord("f"):
        x.add("f")
    q = stdscr.getch()

stdscr.getch()
curses.endwin()
```

Comment: Honestly I prefer developing logic with `colorama`

Comment: Have you ever colorized keywords or functions to different colors than other stdin texts with colorama?

Comment: Your question is about colorizing the `stdin` is it not?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: I can colorize sys.stdin but I couldn't colorize some special words which are in sys.stdin with colorama, since sys.stdin doesn't have a write() method, and i want to colorize the text before pressing the enter key. To colorize some special words with a different color, i try to redirect the sys.stdin to a terminal application. And i thought that this app can be built with curses library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem appears to be the screen-updates.  This version puts the updates after the `x` set is up-to-date:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import curses

stdscr = curses.initscr()
curses.start_color()
curses.init_pair(1, curses.COLOR_RED, curses.COLOR_BLACK)
curses.raw()
curses.noecho()

q = -1
x = set()

while q != ord("q"):
    if q >= 0:
        stdscr.addstr(chr(q))
    if q == ord("d"):
        x.add("d")
    elif q == ord("e"):
        x.add("e")
    elif q == ord("f"):
        x.add("f")
    else:
        x = set()
    if len(x) == 3:
        stdscr.addstr("\b\b\bdef", curses.color_pair(1))
        x = set()
    q = stdscr.getch()

stdscr.getch()
curses.endwin()
```

Comment: Thank you,  problem raises from y=0 and x=0 defination. However in your codes, there's no cursor positions for the characters. In a different example, i tried to change the y and x values according to the stdscr.getmaxyx().  when x is equal to the stdscr.getmaxyx() - 1, the y becomes y += 1 and x  becomes x= 0. But with your codes there's no need to define what the cursor position of the char is on a newline. Thanks.

Comment: Actually there are many problems in my codes, it's not only about x and y. it only add str to the screen if len(x) == 3 in 0,0 position which is impossible to place 3 chr into 1 cell. :)